# NSMutableArray as instance variable alway null

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

After many hours wasted, I officially turn to the experts for help!

My problem lies with using a NSMutableArray as an instance variable, and trying to both add objects and return the array in a method in my class. I am obviously doing something fundamentally wrong and would be grateful for help...I have already tried all the suggestions from other similar questions on stackoverflow, read apples documentation, and basically all combinations of trial and error coding I can think of. The mutable array just alway returns (null). I've even tried creating properties for them, but still the array returns (null) and then I also am running into memory management problems due to the retain while setting the property, and the init in the init method for the class.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1) Loop through a series of UISwitches and if they are 'switched on', add a string to the NSMutableArray

2) Assign this mutable array to another array in another method

Any help much appreciated,

Andy

And for some code...

fruitsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface fruitsViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *fruitsArr;
    UISwitch *appleSwitch;
    UISwitch *orangeSwitch;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *fruitsArr; // ADDED ON EDIT
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *appleSwitch;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *orangeSwitch;

- (IBAction)submitButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

fruitsViewController.m

```
#import "fruitsViewController.h"

@implementation fruitsViewController

@synthesize fruitsArr; // ADDED ON EDIT
@synthesize appleSwitch, orangeSwitch;

/* COMMENTED OUT ON EDIT
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // Allocate memory and initialize the fruits mutable array
        fruitsArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
*/

// VIEW DID LOAD ADDED ON EDIT
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.fruitsArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.fruitsArr = nil;
    self.appleSwitch = nil;
    self.orangeSwitch = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [fruitsArr release];
    [appleSwitch release];
    [orangeSwitch release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)submitButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.appleSwitch isOn]) {
        [self.fruitsArr addObject:@"Apple"; // 'self.' ADDED ON EDIT
    }
    if ([self.orangeSwitch isOn]) {
        [self.fruitsArr addObject:@"Orange"; // 'self.' ADDED ON EDIT
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",self.fruitsArr); // Why is this returning (null) even if the switches are on?!
    [fruitsArr addObject:@"Hello World";
    NSLog(@"%@",self.fruitsArr); // Even trying to add an object outside the if statement returns (null)
}
@end
```

Comment: try to write alloc and init of array in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like your init function is never called. If you're initializing this view controller from a NIB, you need to use initWithCoder. If not, just declare your fruitsArr in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Also, in viewDidUnload, self.fruitArr won't work. You didn't declare it as a property.

Comment: it's `initWithNibName:bundle:` for UIViewControllers, not `initWithCoder:`.

Comment: If the view controller was initialized through Interface Builder, it will use initWithCoder. If it's I initialized manually, then it's up to the person who creates it to call whatever function. The person isn't necessarily initializing it with a nib.

Comment: sorry, I thought only the views have NSCoding protocol, not the viewcontrollers.

Comment: No problem, just thought I'd clarify instead of being a giant butt. My last answer was a bit rude, sorry about that.

Comment: @sgermain06. Thanks so much. I will move the alloc/init to the ViewDidLoad. If I do this, should I call [fruitsArr release] in the ViewDidUnload or keep it in the dealloc method, and set the array to nil on ViewDidUnload? Also, if I do set a property for the fruitsArr, how should this be 'released', as won't there be an extra retain generated? Thanks again, Andy

Comment: Just keep the release in dealloc. Also, using a property makes it easier for memory management, as it takes care of the reference count for you, all you gotta do is set it to nil, no need to release it manually, other than in dealloc.

Comment: @sgermain06. It now works! One last thing...I have edited the code above as you have suggested. Can I just confirm that memory management is now correct? Thanks for the amazingly speedy responses! Andy

Comment: Don't do self.fruitArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; alloc/init increases the retain count and setting it through the property also retains it. Simply do self.fruitArr = [NSMutableArray array];  I edited your post to show what I'm talking about. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use view did load instead of init...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    fruitsArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change that `init` for `viewDidLoad` and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Is your `init` method ever being called (in `complicationsViewController`). Add a NSLog to check this, you might be calling `initWithNib:` maybe.

At `viewDidUnload` you should remove `self.fruitsArr = nil;`, or, if you want to keep it, then initialize the `fruitsArr` in viewDidLoad (and remove it from `init`).

Answer (score 0):

because fruitsArr don't be init.
you should do this first:
     fruitsArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

so, I think you don't run - (id)init before you use fruitsArr.